# Dump a mixture of list and dictionary to xlsx file

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

```
D = [{"abc":[{1: "True", 2:"True", 3:"False"}]},{"bcd":[{1:"False",2:"True",3:"True" }]}]
```

How to dump this list in a xlsx?

```
        1.       2.       3
ABC.    True.    True.    False
Bcd.    False.   True.    True.
```

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried so far and explain the exact problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

Really ugly this could work:

```
row_index = [list(x.keys())[0] for x in D]
column_index = list(list(D[0].values())[0][0].keys())
data = [list(list(x.values())[0][0].values()) for x in D]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=column_index, index=row_index)
df.to_excel("some_name.xlsx")
```